# Php script loading with some html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created an HTML page (index.html) that does a script loading of a PHP page (page.php) :

```
    var DSLScript  = document.createElement("script");
    DSLScript.src  = sUrl;
    DSLScript.type = "text/javascript";
    document.body.appendChild(DSLScript);
    document.body.removeChild(DSLScript);
```

My problem here is that my PHP page also contains some HTML and Javascript. The HTML of `page.php` seems to pose a problem when `index.html` page tries to load the php page:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Is there a header that I can place on the php page to allow `index.html` to process all the PHP code of `page.php`? Or should I convert all the HTML into javascript/DOM, but that may take some time.

Comment: You need to rename index.html to index.php.

Comment: @dcclassics, no he doesn't. He's loading the PHP page from the server, meaning it has already been parsed.  The issue is he's loading page.php as a javascript file but it contains HTML as well, which will throw javascript errors.

Comment: @Robbert oh.   I thought he was trying to put PHP code in the html file.

Comment: Ok, I solved my problem by deleting all the HTML. Which is not a nice 'fix' but that will do.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is trying to put HTML inside of a  tag. This will cause a parse error. The browser will try to evaluate what is inside the  tag as javascript. So, yes, you should convert any inline HTML to string fragments that are dynamically appended or inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the page.php as a Javascript file, then page.php cannot contain any HTML. It must all be JavaScript.  Are you using PHP to create the javascript?  If not, I would take the javascript part out of page.php and save it as it's own javascript file. You can then reference it in page.php as needed and load the js file in your html page.

Comment: yes I'm using php to create the Javascript, it is really intermixed and ugly in my code.

Comment: Your script can't output any HTML. It must be all JavaScript in order for this to work.  It's certainly possible, I've done it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse the entire page as a script, AJAX load the page into a new div element, and extract each  tag and execute it. Here's an example:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

//AJAX get the page
request.open("get", sUrl, true);

//Set even handler for the page load
request.onload = function() {
    //Temporarily place the response content within an active div
    var tDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tDiv.innerHTML = request.response;

    //Get all scripts within the loaded page from the div we placed the content into
    var scriptElems = tDiv.getElementsByTagName("script");

    //Iterate through all the scripts
    for(var i = 0; i < scriptElems.length; i++) {
        //Create a script tag for it
        var tScript = document.createElement("script");

        //Set the content of the new script as the loaded script's text
        tScript.text = scriptElems[i].innerHTML;

        //Add the new script to the head to be evaluated, then remove so there aren't floating scripts in the head
        document.head.appendChild(tScript).parentNode.removeChild(tScript);
    }
};

//Send the request
request.send();
```

Comment: What about if I create a none displayed DIV in which I include the php page?

Comment: I don't know if the scripts would be evaluated. This method makes sure that your scripts are extracted from the loaded page, and then evaluated.

Comment: Your solution looks good, but my code is too intertwined between php and javascript for it to work oO

Comment: What? How so? This script can be dropped into your root .php file as its own `<script>` and made into function to be called whenever you have a new PHP file that needs to be loaded into the page.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Probably because I've got some php inside the script tags.

Comment: It should still work as the PHP is evaluated when it's retrieved from the server. Check in your browser's console for any Javascript errors.